# I need to pass as parameter of a python script the name of the last .csv file created in the folder

Tags: python, bash

I need to pass to a csv2sql script the name of the last .csv file I've created in the working folder.

Could I use this :

`ls -t *.csv | head -1`

to get the output as parameter?

`python csv2sql.py -t products last_created_file.csv  > sql.output`

If I try:

```
python csv2sql.py -t products ls -t *.csv | head -1 > sql.output
```

I get this:

```
csv2sql.py: error: argument csvFile: can't open 'ls': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ls'
```

Comment: this is the output if I try to use that as parameter:

csv2sql.py: error: argument csvFile: can't open 'ls': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ls'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a shell problem.  The common syntax for interpreting command-line output as a single arg for another command line, is the back-quote.  For what I *think* you're doing, this would read:

```
python csv2sql.py -t products `ls -t *.csv | head -1` > sql.output
```

This will

- Execute the `ls` command
- Pipe that to `head`
- Return the single line as an argument to `python`
- Divert the stdout of `python` to `sql.output`

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error because bash does not see `ls -t *.csv | head -1` as an command but as the arguments to the python command (so each word becomes an argument, for example: args[2] would be 'ls', args[3] would be '-t' etc.).

To fix this you could save the output of `ls -t *.csv | head -1` to a variable and then pass the variable to the python command, by saving this as a bash file and then executing it:

```
#!/bin/bash
output=$(ls -t *.csv | head -1)
python csv2sql.py -t products $output | head -1 > sql.output
```

Please do note that I currently don't have access to my linux machine and can't test anything, so I'm assuming that the `ls -t *.csv | head -1` command does what you want it to do.
The solution given above is also not a very tidy one since it uses both bash and python, so personally to I would recommand researching the [subsystem module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) and use that for an all python solution.